# how to confirm that jdbctemplate excuted query succesfully

Tags: hsqldb, jdbctemplate

I am using hsqldb for database. i am using jdbctemplate for sqlqueries. i just want to know how i can confirm that jdbctemplate executed query successfully, as i can't see the result in database, because my database is hsqldb.

Thank in advance

Comment: why can't you connect to your hsqldb and check the results..?
can you provide a code snippet to see what method of the JdbcTemplate are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using HSQLDB as a pure memory DB, you can write out the contents on disc by initializing HSQLDB with the following URL:

```
 jdbc:hsqldb:file:/opt/db/testdb
```

I presume you are using a "memory" URL like this (all contents as you notice are gone after the JVM shuts down):

```
jdbc:hsqldb:mem:mycooldb
```

When you shut down the database after the test, you can either view the resulting script-file using a texteditor, or start the HSQLDB-manager contained in the main HSQLDB jar.

```
java -jar hsqldb-version.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

JdbcTemplate.update(..) returns the number of updated rows as an integer. Check if that is greater than zero or not:

```
if(jdbcTemplate.update("insert into mytable..") > 0) {
  // all ok
} else {
  // not inserted anything
}
```